# Function from Cantor Set to itself.

Tags: analysis, functions, dynamical-systems

I am stuck in getting rational functions  (except identity) defined from Cantor set to itself.

Please help me to get out these functions.

Comment: Are you talking about *the* Cantor set, or *a* Cantor set? The function $f(x)=\mu x(1-x)$, for various values of $\mu\gt4$, is defined on a Cantor-type subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I mean here typically the middle 1/3rd cantor set. Does the function you have mentioned a map from C to C?

Comment: Well, there is also $f(x)=1-x$.

Comment: For $\mu\gt4$, the function $f(x)=\mu x(1-x)$ is a map from a Cantor set $C$ to itself. A Cantor set is defined to be a closed, bounded, perfect, totally disconnected subset of the reals. The middle-thirds set is an example of a Cantor set. The Cantor set $C$ is a subset of $[0,1]$. A proof is given in Elaydi's textbook, Discrete Chaos (but only for the case $\mu\gt2+\sqrt5$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be such that

$
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \cases{
x + \frac{2}{3} & \text{if $x<\frac{1}{2}$} \\
x - \frac{2}{3} & \text{if $x>\frac{1}{2}$}
}
\end{equation}
$

**Edit:** as @studiosus points out, I left out the "rational" part of the requirement.

In this case, I would try to prove that there is no such function. Start by saying that rational functions are $C^\infty$ in their domain, and then relate the distances between points in your "middle-third" Cantor set to the continuiti of the derivative of the function.

Comment: What makes you think that this functions is rational? Or that it preserves any nonempty compact set?

Comment: I completely missed the "rational function" part...

Comment: Do we have a non-linear kind of function from the classical Cantor set to itself? I mean can we define a function f(x)=P(x)/Q(x). where P and Q are quadratic polynomial of x.